# Nopcommerce Override RegisterValidator

Tags: c#, validation, nopcommerce

I want to add another `RuleFor` for `Phone` Field in `RegisterModel` in my plugin.

So, I create a plugin and extend `RegisterValidator` The following form:

```
public partial class RegisterValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisterModel>
{
   public RegisterValidator(ILocalizationService localizationService)
   {
      RuleFor(x => x.Phone)
      .Matches(@"^(0|\+98)?([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}){8}$")
      .WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Account.Fields.Phone.InvalidMobileNumber"));
   }
}
```

But this not work.

Generally, how can exchange `RegisterValidator` in my plugin?!

Please advice me,if possible.

Answer (score 1):

`RegisterValidator` is a partial class and you cannot write a partial class across projects. Partial classes have to exist in the same assembly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what's the solution for this issue. I want to add another RuleFor to RegisterValidator Or change email status to optional in RegisterModel in CustomerController. Please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HamidN.CH: in that case, you may have to use your model and Validator.